# Remote desktop connection disconnect rarely

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-10

1. We have two offices that are connected with a cable network.
2. **Office 1** uses IP range like 90.0.0.XXX for its clients.
3. **Office 2** uses IP range like 90.0.2.XXX for its clients.
4. I'm using windows 10 pro on my machine in **office 1**.
5. We have a windows server 2008 R2 machine in **office 2**.
6. I can ping the server IP on my machine always without any request timed out.

When I connect to Sql Server Management Studio 2008 R2 on the server through  SSMS 2008 R2 on my machine or when I try to use remote desktop connection to the server from my machine everything works fine but every 2 or 3 minutes SSMS or RDC disconnect from the server and I have to login again.
also we don't have this issue on Windows 7 machines in **office 1**.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Sound like it's related to a UDP "connection" that is terminated on the VPN/Routers (if Win7 doesn't have the RDP 8 update applied).

Try to disable UDP on a Windows 10 workstation and see if it's stable - if it's stable, make sure your network equipment doesn't terminate the UDP "connections".

1. Navigate to

   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services\Client
2. Create a DWORD named fClientDisableUDP and assign it a value of 1 .